Laravel 10 joinSub fromSub Expression is broken for cross database connections str_starts_with(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string
After upgrading to Laravel 10 my eloquent query using joinSub fromSub returns an error
error evaluating code: str_starts_with(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression given

My query looks something like that (simplified version)
DB::connection('connection1')
->table('table1')
->joinSub(DB::connection('connection2')->query()
    ->fromSub(function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder
            ->from('table2')
            ->select(['emailId', 'link'])
            ->selectRaw('COUNT(link) as total')
            ->groupBy(['emailId', 'link'])
            ->orderByDesc('total');
    }, 'clicked')
    ->select('clicked.emailId')
    ->groupBy(['clicked.emailId'])
, 'clicked2', 'clicked2.emailId', '=', 'email.id'
)
->select('table1.*')
->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(clicked2.totals) as clicked_links');

It used to work in Laravel <10 but now when a method prependDatabaseNameIfCrossDatabaseQuery() in \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder gets executed (see code below) it breaks at ! str_starts_with($query->from, $databaseName) because $query->from is an Expression and __toString() has been removed from it in Laravel 10
protected function prependDatabaseNameIfCrossDatabaseQuery($query)
{
    if ($query->getConnection()->getDatabaseName() !==
        $this->getConnection()->getDatabaseName()) {
        $databaseName = $query->getConnection()->getDatabaseName();

        if (! str_starts_with($query->from, $databaseName) && ! str_contains($query->from, '.')) {
            $query->from($databaseName.'.'.$query->from);
        }
    }

    return $query;
}

Any ideas how to fix this? As I can't seemed to apply $expression->getValue(DB::connection()->getQueryGrammar()); mentioned in the documentation as I don't use DB::raw( and don't cast it to string in my code.
